# Why is this thread pausing when "getstr" is used in another thread? Python Curses

Tags: python, python-curses

I have made a thread that is supposed to show the seconds passing. Unfortunately, when I use `getstr` from the `curses` module the whole script stops, including the thread. I have to use a thread lock to stop random characters being printed out because of overlapping orders.

Any suggestions on how to fix this or an alternative would be great!

In the below example `window` and `window2` are already set-up...

```
lock = threaing.Lock()


def main_function():
  #starts thread
  t1 = threading.Thread(target=time_calc,args=(window2,))
  t1.start()
  #Gets user input
  while True:
    data = window1.addstr(y,x,"Type something in!")
    data = window1.getstr(y,x,5)

    lock.acquire()
    window1.erase()
    txt = "You said: "+data

    window1.addstr(y,x,txt)
    lock.release()


def time_calc(window2):
  current_count = 0

  while True:

    time += 1

    text = "Time Count: "+str(time)

    lock.acquire()
    window2.erase()

    window2.addstr(y,x,text)
    lock.release()

    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The problem with my code

I figured out the problem with my code. You **can't** run a thread inside a thread for some reason and I originally had my `main` function called to be considered a thread.  I guess I should have stated this in my question. Sorry

> There is probably a way to run a thread in a thread, but this did **not** work for me.

## My Updated Code

```
lock = threading.Lock()

def call_threads():
  t1 = threading.Thread(target=main_function,args=(window1,))
  t1.start()

  t2 = threading.Thread(target=time_calc,args=(window2,))
  t1.start()

def main_function(window1):
  #Gets user input
  while True:
    data = window1.addstr(y,x,"Type something in!")
    data = window1.getstr(y,x,5)

    lock.acquire()
    window1.erase()
    txt = "You said: "+data

    window1.addstr(y,x,txt)
    lock.release()


def time_calc(window2):
  current_count = 0

  while True:

    time += 1

    text = "Time Count: "+str(time)

    lock.acquire()
    window2.erase()

    window2.addstr(y,x,text)
    lock.release()

    time.sleep(1)
```

#### If there is anything else that may have caused this error, please comment it!